# Failed to initialize widget model is not set in yii

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I'm getting error when i creating a Modal Login widget using Yii-Bootstrap extension.

CException Error - **TbInput: Failed to initialize widget! Model is not set.**

What is the wrong???

Here is my source code -

**Login Button code** -

```
in /views/layouts/main.php

<?php if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest): ?>
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'size' => 'large',
            'label' => 'login',
            'url' => '#login-modal',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
              'data-toggle' => 'modal',
              'onclick' => '$("#error-div").hide();$("#LoginForm_username").focus();'),
            )
         );

         endif;

      $this->renderPartial("_ajax_login_form");
    ?>
```

**ajax_login_form.php**

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
        'id' => 'login-modal'
          )
      ); ?>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h3>login</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'LoginForm',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'well'),
            )
         );
?>
    <div id="error-div" class="alert alert-block alert-error" style="display:none;">
    </div>    
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($login_form_model, 'username', array(
                            'class' => 'span3'
                            )
                      ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordFieldRow($login_form_model, 'password', array(
                             'class' => 'span3'
                             )
                      ); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType' => 'ajaxSubmit', 
            'icon' => 'ok', 
            'label' => 'Submit', 
            'ajaxOptions' => array(
            'success' => 
      'function(data){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(obj.login=="success"){
            $("#login-modal").modal("hide");
            setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true);},400);
        }else{
            $("#error-div").show();
            $("#error-div").html("");
            if("LoginForm_password" in obj){
                $("#error-div").html(obj.LoginForm_password[0]+"<br />");
            }
            if("LoginForm_username" in obj){
                $("#error-div").append(obj.LoginForm_username[0]);
            }
        }
    }'),
));

 $this->endWidget(); ?>
     </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionLogin(){

  //$this->layout = 'main';
  $model = new LoginForm();

  if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form')
    {
      echo CActiveForm::validate($model, array('username', 'password', 'verifyCode'));
      Yii::app()->end();
    }

  if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $login_form_model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        if ($login_form_model->validate() and $login_form_model->login()) {
            $array = array('login' => 'success');
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Successfully logged in.');
            $json = json_encode($array);
            echo $json;
            Yii::app()->end();
        } else {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($login_form_model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }

  $this->render('login', array(
    'model' => $model,
    ));
 }
```

**login.php**

```
<?php 

 $form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
      'id' => 'login-form',
      'enableClientValidation' => true,
      'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'well'),
      'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        ),
     )); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'username', array('class' => 'span3'));?>
<?php echo $form->passwordFieldRow($model, 'password', array('class' => 'span3'));?> 
<?php echo $form->checkBoxRow($model, 'rememberMe');?>
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType' => 'submit', 'type' => 'primary', 'label' => 'Submit', 'icon' => 'ok'));?>
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType' => 'reset', 'label' => 'Reset'));?>
 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Please help me to resolve my error.

Comment: You are not passing `$login_form_model` to the view in your SiteController. It should be something like `$this->render('login', array(
    'model' => $model, 'login_form_model' => $login_form_model,

    ));`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Please can you update my SiteController.php???

Comment: @ThinkDifferent still not working... same error display.

Comment: As I see from your SiteController if you change your actionLogin to the following answer, it should work.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent hey need your help... can you give me your email id???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is generated because you don't pass the `$model` correctly to the view.

Change you `actionLogin()` in your `SiteController.php`  to

```
public function actionLogin(){

 //$this->layout = 'main';
 $model = new LoginForm();

 if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form')
 {
    echo CActiveForm::validate($model, array('email', 'password', 'verifyCode'));
    Yii::app()->end();
 }

 if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
    if ($model->validate() and $model->login()) {
        $array = array('login' => 'success');
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Successfully logged in.');
        $json = json_encode($array);
        echo $json;
        Yii::app()->end();
    } else {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
 }

 $this->render('login', array(
    'model' => $model,
  ));
}
```

Changes needed in your main.php file

```
 $login_form_model = new LoginForm();
 $this->renderPartial("_ajax_login_form",  array( 
                        'login_form_model' => $login_form_model,
                         )
                     );
```

Comment: still display same error - TbInput: Failed to initialize widget! Model is not set.

Comment: Ahhhh yes its in the main.php layout, you are not passing the model even there

Comment: You need to pass the model in this line `$this->renderPartial("_ajax_login_form");`. It is because of this you get the error.

Comment: if i'm update my TbInput.php then it's work but when i'm click on Login button. i'm getting error in modal like - Fatal error: Class TbInputVertical contains 18 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (TbInput::toggleButton, TbInput::checkBoxGroupsList, TbInput::passfieldField, ...)

Comment: I won't suggest to edit the core files. I have updated the answer but I think you don't change the activeform actions according to you controller and actions. For example you have put code n your main.php layout, it will work on login page but wonn't work on other pages. Anyway that is another issue. I have updated the answer can you check and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: hey thanks... now it's working fine.. can you suggest me how to implement validation???

Comment: that is good. Sure I will what you need to validate? If you just need that username and password are not empty then just add the rule under the rules() function in your LoginForm model like: `return array(
            array('username, password', 'required'),`

Comment: I have rules in LoginForm model like: `return array(             array('username, password', 'required')` but it's not working, when i'm click on submit button through modal but its working fine in login.php. suggest me what i do now?

Comment: I think you are using Ajax that is why it not validating. For this you need to go through this simple ***[Tutorial](http://learnyii.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/yii.html)***